# Get `numpy.void` or equivalent keyable object by using raw pointer in buffer c api

Tags: python, c++, numpy, pybind11

I am trying to return the specific row of a numpy array back to python. My current method is

```
pybind11::object NumpyIndex::getRow(int64_t row, pybind11::array& array)
{
    auto pyLong = PyLong_FromLong(row);
    auto it = PyObject_GetItem(array.ptr(), pyLong);
    Py_DECREF(pyLong);
    return pybind11::reinterpret_steal<pybind11::object>(it);
}
```

However i do not like this as i want to directly access the `void*` of the row to create the `numpy.void`/`scalar` object? How can i create a scalar by using the dtype and pointer. Or change the ptr of a numpy.void object already created. It is too slow to use the array. I want todo something like

```
auto* ptr = static_cast<char*>(bufInfo_.ptr)[row] *strideSize]
auto scalarPyObject = make_scalar(dtype_, ptr);
```

or be able to change the pointer of an already made numpy.void

```
pybind11::object NumpyIndex::getRow(int64_t row) {
   auto* ptr = static_cast<char*>(bufInfo_.ptr)[row] *strideSize]
   saveNumpyVoid_.set_ptr(ptr)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: yup! Using pybind, python c-api, and numpy c-api and compiling in c++ 20

Comment: the records of a structured array are `np.void` objects, with length determined by the compound dtype.